# Flutter - how to get current context?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase cloud messaging for notifications, and i want to show a dialog or snackbar once i receive a notification when i am inside the application, my problem is that i am initializing the firebase configuration at the top of my widget tree (Splash screen once the app is starting)

```
_fireBaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    dynamic data = message['data'];
    ................ // Adding a snackbar/alertdialog here doesn't work
  },
);
```

obviously if i set a dialog or snackbar it won't show since i need the context of my current page, is there any way to get the current context?

I also tried putting it inside the build widget of my splash screen but still the dialog isn't showing once i am on another page.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _fireBaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        dynamic data = message['data'];
        if (data['id'] == '1') {
          newPro = true;
        } else if (data['id'] == '2') {
          print("THIS WORKS!!!");
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                    content: ListTile(
                      title: Text("TEST"),
                      subtitle: Text("TEST"),
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text("OK"),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ));
        }
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up using Overlay support:

> https://pub.dev/packages/overlay_support

It is basically called at the very beginning of my tree just like wrapping providers at the main.dart, it worked like a charm, nothing else worked at all! 
Also here is a tutorial that helped me a lot:

> https://medium.com/flutter-community/in-app-notifications-in-flutter-9c1e92ea10b3

Comment: Using packages to accomplish little means is not a very good practice. As a rule of thumb, make sure you need more than half of the package's methods before installing it.

Answer (score 14):

I had the exact same issue, but I found a brilliant thread on GitHub. Basically, you can create a navigatorKey and pass that in to MaterialApp, and then use that navigatorKey to change route.

See how in this thread: https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/5#issuecomment-361215074

Comment: That was indeed a brilliant thread. This I think should have been the accepted answer as this is the best way to solve the problem stated

Comment: Thanks my friend!!! it helps me a lot!!!

Comment: Although it's nice with a brief and to-the-point answer, instead of an entire github thread... Github threads are often chaotic and endless! It's scary to click them! :-/

Answer (score 7):

An elegant solution to this problem is to use `GlobalKey`. That'll let you find the current BuildContext and do things with it.

You make a file called eg. `global.dart` looking like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GlobalVariable {
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navState = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

You use this in your `main()` and `MaterialApp()` like this:

```dart
import 'global.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'fcm.dart';  // My Firebase Cloud Messaging code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'screens/welcome_screen.dart';


void main() {
  print('Running main()');
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  initializeFcm('', GlobalVariable.navState); // Sending the global key when initializing Firebase Cloud Messaging
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
      navigatorKey: GlobalVariable.navState,  // Putting the global key in the MaterialApp
    );
  }
}
```

Then, in the file that handles Firebase Cloud Messaging, which I've named `fcm.dart`, you'll be able to use the `GlobalKey` to find the current `context` and use it, for example like this:

```dart
import 'package:blackbox/global.dart';
import 'online_screens/game_hub_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

void initializeFcm(String token, GlobalKey myGlobalKey) async {
  print('Initializing Firebase Cloud Messaging...');
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((remoteMsg) {
    // Using the currentContext found with GlobalKey:
    Navigator.push(GlobalVariable.navState.currentContext, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return GameHubScreen();
    }));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because it makes me uncomfortable to have the answer embedded in a link, here is the answer (credit to `xqwzts` on Github).

Use a GlobalKey you can access from anywhere to navigate:

##### Create the key:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

##### Pass it to your App:

```
new MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    );
```

##### Push routes:

```
navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('/someRoute');
```

Answer (score 0):

do the initializing inside a build method of your first widget in the tree ! which normally it called an App widget and it is StateLess StateFull widget and inside the build method you have access to the BuildContext

Comment: Already tried that, it didn't work, it's printing but no dialog is showing.