# Flutter Firebase messaging - push notification is not showing when app is open

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

I'm new to flutter and I'm just trying to receive firebase push notifications to my flutter app. Push notifications are receiving when the app is closed and in the background. But when the app is open, push notification is receiving, but it's not showing the alert notification (I want to show the push notification title and body as an alert in my app if it's opened). Here's my code for it.

```
_fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            content: ListTile(
              title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
              subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Ok'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I was able to manage my issue by using **overlay_support** package

I have referred the following question links:

[Flutter - Firebase Messaging Snackbar not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598448/flutter-firebase-messaging-snackbar-not-showing)

[Flutter - how to get current context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59594369/flutter-how-to-get-current-context/59599602#59599602)

and I managed my issue by following the below tutorial and package

tutorial: https://medium.com/flutter-community/in-app-notifications-in-flutter-9c1e92ea10b3

package: https://pub.dev/packages/overlay_support/install

I wrapped my `MaterialApp()` widget in the `OverlaySupport()` widget.

```
return OverlaySupport(
            child: MaterialApp(....
               
          ));
```

and then I add `showOverlayNotification` to my _fcm.configure --> onMessage:

```
_fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        showOverlayNotification((context) {
          return Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
            child: SafeArea(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: SizedBox.fromSize(
                    size: const Size(40, 40),
                    child: ClipOval(
                        child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ))),
                title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
                subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
                trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                    onPressed: () {
                      OverlaySupportEntry.of(context).dismiss();
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 4000));

        print(message['notification']['title']);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package to display a snackBar when the user receives a notification while the app is in the Foreground.

```
_fcm.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    Get.snackbar("message['notification']['title']", snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,);
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
  },
);
```

The 'snackPosition' parameter allows the snackBar to be displayed at the top, hence appearing as an alert message.

There is a good explanation of how to use the flutter_local_notifications package in conjunction with FCM [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/)

Answer (score 2):

FCM provides you with three callbacks. `OnResume`, `OnLaunch` and `OnMessage`.

When the app is in foreground, the `onMessage` is triggered, and it gives you the opportunity to carry out any custom action.

In order to show a notification while the app is in foreground, you can make use of
[Flutter Local Notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package.

You might not be able to see an alert dialog due to the lack of context inside onMessage callback. Try wrapping the `_fcm.configure` inside

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){ [_fcm.configure block] });
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){ [_fcm.configure block] }); but still the alert dialog is not showing

Comment: Why are you using "showOverlayNotification"? You could just use showDialog and pass an Alert dialog to the showDialog method. 
Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

Guys if you have connected your phone to your pc and are testing it it will not show notifications .Same thing happened to me so i built the apk then tried it again it actually worked

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was following a tutorial (he used an emulator). And he used the firebase cloud messaging website to push a notification. I tried it as well but it did not show anything. Glad I know why it was not working :D

Answer (score 2):

Actually default behavior of Android is like **not showing notification when app is open**.

So, if you want to show notification when App is open then `add below line after initializing FirebaseApp and FirebaseMessaging`
.

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(alert: true,badge: true,sound: true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The new methods to handle the notification when the app is opened are as below:

```
  // Called when the app is in background state
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    await _handleMessage(message);
  });

  // Called when the app is in foreground (open)
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    await _handleMessage(message);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To Show Notification in Flutter you can use [Flutter Local Notification Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)